# Process.Kill() is causing fatal error in Winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, process

today I want to open application inside of form, but it cause error.

```
                if (File.Exists(ts3))
                {
                    Process p = Process.Start(ts3);
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
                }

                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(ts3check))
                {
                    process.Kill();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Process p = Process.Start(ts3);
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
```

It should check, if this app is already openned, if it is, kill it and open new one inside of my form. But when I try to open process in form, it will cause fatal error and makes my form stopped working. I'm looking at it for like half a hour and I can't see it.

EDIT: app works if app is not already openned, but if it is, it will execute this part of code and make the error

```
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(ts3check))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Process p = Process.Start(ts3);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
```

Comment: There really isn't enough to go on here. What is the error you're getting, is there a stack trace? Have you tried replacing your `Thread.Sleep(2000)` with `p.WaitForInputIdle()`?

Comment: @chancea No it's killing app teamspeak3

Comment: @vane problem is, it won't lock teamspeak into my form

Comment: In your edit you narrow down where the error is happening, but do you know the exact line that is causing the error? You can find this out in the debugger. Which exact line is causing the problem? `process.Kill()`, `process.Start(ts3)` or the `SetParent` call? Also, what is the exact error message or exception that is occurring?

Comment: @PepaGazdoš: I've edited your post to focus on problematic part. Please, specify exactly which line caused an error, and what was the values at this point. Best regards,

Comment: @vane `p.WaitForInputIdle()` solved the error problem, but it is not locking into panel in form.

Comment: It might have something to do with the way TeamSpeak was programmed. Try replacing TeamSpeak with notepad and see if it works with that, if it does, this might not be a possible solution to embed TeamSpeak

Comment: I okay I solved whole problem.
                    `Process p = Process.Start(ts3);
                    p.WaitForInputIdle();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);`
I've added System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); To wait until app will open and then lock it in.

Comment: If that works in your particular situation, great. Keep in mind though, that using `Sleep` is not a recommended approach since the results could be different on different systems (i.e. TeamSpeak may take 1.5 seconds to launch on your system but 4 seconds on another). Here is a link to a control someone made that does exactly what you want http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project

Comment: @vane thank you, can I add you points or somethings like that?

Comment: I put my comments into an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `Thread.Sleep(2000)` to `p.WaitForInputIdle()` and you might also want to take a look at [Hosting EXE Applications in a WinForm project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project) over at CodeProject; someone has created a control to do exactly what you're looking for.